# TPH Inheritance - Inherited Object Retrieval along with base class

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core

In a scenario like the below image:

[image]

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Person.ToList();
}
```

> **It does not retrieve the inherited objects - student and instructor by default.**
>
> This was not the case with EF 6.
>
> Is there any work around for this right now.

Comment: `Person` is abstract so it can't return `Person`s either.

Comment: OK, so you made `Person` not abstract. Doesn't matter. The subtypes *are* returned, but their compile-time type is `Person`. If you need the subtypes you have to cast them.